# Adding border messes up layout

Tags: css, layout, grid, border

For some reason adding a border to some of the divs in a grid will mess up the spacing.

Here is jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/gvcuLbbc/

```
body{
    background-color:#f6db05;
}

#container{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#grid{
    align-content: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20%;
    }

.smallcontainer{
    height:200px;
    width:28%;
    margin:2%;
    float:left;
}

.textcontainer{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I've tried increasing the size of their container but it didnt help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a `border-box` model. Use this at the first:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uys5mm1y/**